# What is the time complexity of this function, that generates all unique factor combinations of a number?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, math, time-complexity, factors

Hello I just solved leetcode 254 [https://leetcode.com/problems/factor-combinations/], the objective of this algorithm is to find all unique combinations of the factors for a given number `n`(example: for `n = 8` we return `[[2 x 2 x 2], [2 x 4]]`) and wrote the code below:

```
def getFactors(self, n: int) -> List[List[int]]:
    def helper(n, cur, path, ind, factors):
        if cur == n:
            res.append(path[:])
            return

        for i in range(ind, len(factors)):
            if cur * factors[i] <= n:
                path.append(factors[i])
                helper(n, cur * factors[i], path, i, factors)
                path.pop()

    res = []
    helper(n, 1, [], 0, [num for num in range(2, n) if n % num == 0])
    return res if res != [[]] else []
```

The way this algorithm works is I iterate over all the factors and multiply `cur` by the factor I am iterating over and as long as `cur * factors[i] <= n` I can add that factor to my `path` and keep recursing.

I can't figure out the time complexity in terms of `n` though. I can say that in the worst case the recursion tree is gonna have depth `log n` (that would be `2 x 2 x 2 ... x 2` if `n` is a power of 2) but I am stuck on making sense of the branching factor for this tree.

Any help to calculate the time complexity of this algorithm is welcome, but I would be very grateful for an intuitive way to look at it (something I can replicate in an interview)... more formal methods are also welcome.

EDIT 1:

So I can say this recurrence has `log(n)` branches (number of factors) and `log(n)` depth in the worst case resulting in a runtime of `O(log(n)^log(n))` is this reasoning good ?

EDIT 2:

However another way of looking at it is we have `O(log(n))` factors and we are just doing a subset of all the possible combinations, which is a `2^n` exercise thus resulting in `2^log(n) = n` different solutions. And for each of the `n` solutions we have `log(n)` (tree depth) multiplications resulting in a `O(nlog(n))` runtime ... so my question --> Which analysis is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

One observation:

The number of factors of `n` in the worst case happens when n is the product of a consecutive number of the smallest primes. I.e. 2*3*5*7*11 etc.

I was curious about how fast this number grows, as a function of n (again, in the worst case). Using Python, and looking at the first 100 or so primes, it seems the 10-based logarithm of n grows a little bit faster than the number of factors in n. For small values, the numbers are almost the same, but the difference keeps getting bigger and after 70 or so factors (that is - the product of the 70 first primes), the logarithm is more than twice the number of factors.

Another way of putting it is that `[number of factors of n]` grows slower than `log n`.

Comment: This is a well-studied problem and, indeed, the average number of divisors of n is log n.

Comment: Yes indeed James, I did find that information --> So I can say this recurrence has `log(n) branches and log(n) depth` in the worst case resulting in a runtime of `O(log(n)^log(n))` do you agree ?

Comment: However another way of looking at it is we have `O(log(n))` factors and we are just doing a subset of all the possible combinations, which is a `2^n` exercise thus resulting in `2^log(n) = n` different solutions. And for each of the `n` solutions we have `log(n)` (tree depth) multiplications resulting in a `O(nlog(n))` runtime ... so my question to you @James... which analysis is correct ?

Comment: @d_darric: I prefer to call them *divisors*, because that's what they seemed to be called in the literature, although *factors* is also correct. I said it was well-studied, but not by me :) I just though it was cool that the answerer did some careful experiments and came up with a conjecture that was correct. I might look at the problem a little bit today.

Answer (score 0):

The general case of time complexity is `T(n) = sum_{i=1}{number of factors of n}(T(n/f_i)) + c` (`f_i`s are factors of `n`). If `n = 2^k`, the time complexity is `T(n) = log(n) T(n/2) + c`. Hence:

```
T(n) = log(n) T(n/2) + c = 
       log(n) (log(n/2) T(n/2^2) + c) + c = 
       log(n) log(n/2) T(n/2^2) + c (1 + log(n)) = 
       k * (k-1) * T(n/2^2) +‌c (1 + k) = 
       k * (k-1) * (log(n/2^2) T(n/2^3) + c) + c (1 + k) = 
       k * (k-1) * (k-2) T(n/2^3) +‌c (1 + k + k * (k-1)) = Omega(log(n)!)
```

We used the `Omega` because it is just for the case of `2^k`. To know more about the complexity, you need to scrutinize more into the general term.